Android jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet disable outside touch and drag
I'm using ModalBottomSheet
I don't want ModalBottomSheet to close when I touch the outside area.
And I also want to stop it from being dragged. What should I do?

You can achieve the desired behaviour just by setting two parameters.
Just assign empty lambda to onDismissRequest and assign null to dragHandle like this:
ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = {}, // this will prevent outside touch
    dragHandle = null, // this will not show the drag option
    //... other parameters
) {
    //... bottom sheet content here
}


In order to make the ModalBottomSheet to not dismissed and dragged, you first create a modal state then set skipPartiallyExpanded.
// States
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    skipPartiallyExpanded = false
)

var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

And in the Composable dismiss request event, do nothing.
// Modal Bottom Sheet
if (showBottomSheet) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = {  
            //showBottomSheet = false 
        },
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        containerColor = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        // Views
    }
}


When I do this, drag it and it's a bounce. I don't want the bounce to work.
